# DAG-Concurrency per Worker in Apache Airflow

Tags: concurrency, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Hi friends of Apache Airflow

**Is it possible to configure the number of DAG-Runs on each worker since worker concurrency only refers to tasks?**

This is an **example** of the challenge I face:

Lets say I have a DAG called `My-DAG` with 2 parallel tasks called `A` and `B`.
I got `12 worker VM's` for scaling things up.
Each machine can run one My-DAG (A and B in parallel) according to benchmarks.

I would **configure** the following:

- parallelism = 32 (since thats enough for this example)
- max_active_runs/max_active_runs_per_dag = 12 (1 per worker)
- max_active_tasks_per_dag = 24 (12 DAG runs times 2 parallel tasks A and B)
- worker-concurrency = 2 (2 tasks
  per worker with the assumption that one DAG runs per worker)

The last bullet point shows my dilemma.
If I think about it, it could happen that one worker runs twice the task A or twice the task B.

I know a new benchmark based on tasks would make sense, however I am really interested in knowing whether this would be possible and what the best approach would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a great solution from Jens Scheffler in the Apache Airflow Slack group.

> Implement two workers per VM and add a label with "queueA" and
> "queueB" to the workers and ensure that taks of type A are only routed
> to "queueA" workers and vice versa

As a result, I would need to set the worker-concurrency to 1.